# Save WriteableBitmap to file using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap

I have:

```
WriteableBitmap bmp;
```

I basicly want to save it into a file on the disk like the following:

```
C:\bmp.png
```

I read some forums which mentions to read:

```
bmp.Pixels
```

and save those pixels into a `Bitmap` then use `Bitmap.SaveImage()` function. However, I can't access any `Pixels`. Apperantly my `WriteableBitmap` does not have any property named `Pixels`.

I use .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Just want to mention that `WriteableBitmap.Pixels` is a property in Silverlight. It is not available in WPF-

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thanks for the comment. I wasn't aware of it. Cheers.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use your WriteableBitmap's clone and use this function as below:

```
CreateThumbnail(filename, _frontBitmap.Clone());
```

...

```
void CreateThumbnail(string filename, BitmapSource image5)
{
    if (filename != string.Empty)
    {
         using (FileStream stream5 = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
         {
             PngBitmapEncoder encoder5 = new PngBitmapEncoder();
             encoder5.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image5));
             encoder5.Save(stream5);
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to call `stream.Close()`? Won't `Dispose()` do that automatically?