# Saving WriteableBitmap to PNG

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to save WriteableBitmap into PNG with Transparent background. Is there a different between PNG and PNG with Transparency? appreciate your help. Please show me the sample code. Thanks

Comment: check out http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen: Thanks. Had checked it out. It does not support such operation.

Comment: @MilkBottle Have you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the following links. May that could help you out.

[Save WriteableBitmap to file using WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212771/save-writeablebitmap-to-file-using-wpf)

[Saving Bitmap as PNG on WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378946/saving-bitmap-as-png-on-wp7)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/272722/Converting-WriteableBitmap-to-a-Bitmap-for-saving

):

Comment: Thanks. The Encoder used in WPF not in WP and the second link point to JohnPapa, Is this the PNG or PNG with Transparency background and can the Tool be used in WP? Thanks