# Generate .bmp image in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, 2d, bmp

I would like to generate a two dimensional array of pixels and then save it in .bmp file. I've read about **Bitmaps**, but I don't fully understand how to convert 2D arrays of Integer to **Bitmap image**.

That's what I've already found and tried to make

```
        // Create array of integers
        int width = 1024;
        int height = 768;
        int[] integers = new int[width * height];

        // Fill array with random values
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < integers.Length; ++i)
        {
            integers[i] = random.Next(Int32.MaxValue);
        }

        // Copy into bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* intPtr = &integers[0])
            {

            bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, width, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(&integers[0]));
            }
        }
```

However I still don't understand this part

```
        // Copy into bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* intPtr = &integers[0])
            {

            bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, width, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(&integers[0]));
            }
        }
```

1. The compiler says *The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*
2. How can I put it into the bmp file?

Comment: Please show what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old compiler ... did you try his suggestion ?

Add this line in the top of your file :

```
using System.Drawing.Bitmap;
```

If you want more : check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

By the way, you can right-click on `Bitmap` and select `Resolve` to do it. This is the easy way.

To save your image into a file, there is differents ways to do it. It depends of which platform you are. I think you should look in [WriteableImageEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) or [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11212771/save-writeablebitmap-to-file-using-wpf) or [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/73cb15de-5bea-4d82-b5ef-821deb09ce44/how-to-save-image-in-folder-in-c-window-application?forum=winforms)

Comment: Not all errors are solved by VS' suggestions, but this is the right answer.

Comment: Sure, you may have to add a reference if you dont have it.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with Bitmap solved. But how can I save my bitmap in a .bmp file?

Comment: I just edited my answer for the second question.

Comment: Just check has solved and be happy in c# programming !